# mod_rewrite with anchor link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, anchor

I know you can't redirect anchor URLs to another page, but is it possible to redirect a URL to only a single anchor?

So

```
http://www.example.com/video/{title}
```

always gets sent to

```
http://www.example.com/video.php?title={title}#player
```

The only thing that changes is the title, anchor is always the same. I need to redirect to a certain slide on a coda slider

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/video/(.*) /video.php?title=$1#player [NE,L,R=301]
```

NE|noescape

By default, special characters, such as & and ?, for example, will be converted to their hexcode equivalent. Using the [NE] flag prevents that from happening.

Source : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: NE-Flag is unknown for ```Apache/2.4.6```. 
```httpd -V``` logs the following: ```RewriteCond: unknown flag 'NE'```

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to use the `#` sign in a redirect rule if you specify the `NE` flag (No Escape)

Comment: Thanks Dan, it seems to need the 301 redirect too

Comment: I didn't need the 301, but if you are using a permanent redirect, hitting refresh in your browser will likely use the cached (escaped) redirect rule.  Clear your cache or try with another browser.