# rewrite url for deeplinking

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

What i'm trying to do is quite simple but none of the stackoverflow answers address this exactly:

How do i use .htaccess to insert a hash tag in between the base url and the route requested?

ie

```
http://mydomain.com/shop
```

will become

```
http://mydomain.com/#/shop
```

i want to use .htaccess because i feel like its a cleaner solution than server side php.
it the reason i can do this is because i'm using jquery address which takes over the links on the page replacing the href attribute. it just breaks if the hash tag isn't properly getting put in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mod_rewrite with anchor link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686075/mod-rewrite-with-anchor-link)

Answer (score 2):

Just use bog-standard mod_rewrite with the "no-escape" (NE) option:

```
RewriteRule ^shop /\#/shop [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: You don't prefix the match pattern with a forward-slash in per-directory config, ie `.htaccess`

Comment: I meant the `^/shop` bit. Should be `^shop`

Comment: Feh. Updated again.  I should really come back and test tomorrow to make sure it's correct.  Thanks again, phil.

Comment: but i really just want it to put a hash in between ANYTHING (*) after the base url.

Answer (score 1):

[The hash/number symbol (#) itself has a special significance in a URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), so you cannot reliably place it into the path of your URL. You can do this:

```
RewriteRule ^shop(.*) /hash/shop$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is helpful for deeplinking.You need to validate the browser and redirect to the app store if the module is not installed ,if installed means it will redirect to inside the app.

```
//Validate browser
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari') == !FALSE) {
?>
<script>
    window.location = 'deeplinkexample://';
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple/id1145838819?l=fr&ls=1&mt=8'
    }, 250);enter code here
</script>
<?php
}
```