# .htaccess Rewrite urls with location hash

Tags: php, .htaccess

What I have is a url like this:

```
domain.com/index.php?chapter=chapter-name
```

and a url link this:

```
domain.com/index.php?marker=marker-name
```

What I want is:

```
domain.com/#chapter-name
```

and this:

```
domain.com/#chapter-name/marker-name
```

How can I do this with .htaccess?

I now have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ index.php?chapter=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?chapter=$1
```

Thanks!

Comment: '#' is an URL fragment, using it in this way may not have the effect you're after : http://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/

Comment: You cant do it via htaccess, use Javascript instead.

Comment: Would the second request actually be: domain.com/index.php?chapter=chapter-name&marker=marker-name ?

Comment: Apache can rewrite to anchor tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686075/mod-rewrite-with-anchor-link

Answer (score 0):

To get the chapter working, try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php\?chapter=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/#$1
```

Your second needs is a arbitrary... how does the marker "know" which chapter... Maybe you meant this on your second request:

```
domain.com/index.php?chapter=chapter-name&marker=marker-name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Basically `#` is a client thing, and never sent to the server. `.htaccess` therefore will not work.