# .htaccess redirect to # anchor link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Is it possible to redirect a URL to another URL ending in a hash for a page anchor link?

The # part will be hard coded, not picked up by from the browser request.

Here's what I've been trying:

```
RewriteRule ^birmingham/events.html /#events [R=301,NE,L]
```

The above just takes me to the homepage without the #events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mod\_rewrite with anchor link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686075/mod-rewrite-with-anchor-link)

Comment: Do you have any other rewrite rules in htaccess?

Comment: @Starkeen I've tried removing all the other rules & just having <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>RewriteEngine On above it and </IfModule> after it with the same results.

Comment: I've tried the solution in your link @Croises but it has no affect.

Comment: Your rule is working fine on my apache server, did you try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Can't believe how dim I've been, caching was the issue! Should I or yourself add that as an answer & accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, as @Starkeen said, browser caching. Once that was cleared it all worked.