# Issues with RewriteRule on Generic Anchor Redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to redirect any request to the root of my site to an anchor on the index. So

```
https://example.com/foo
```

Gets sent to

```
https://example.com/#foo
```

I've written this .htaccess file (it also redirects http requests to https, that part works, but is included for completeness)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /#$1 [NE,R=302]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Based on the discussion in this thread: [mod_rewrite with anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686075/mod-rewrite-with-anchor-link) this should work, but it's not matching for some reason. I tried out the rule given in that thread using this tool: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it doesn't seem to work there either.

I've tried clearing my cache and accessing in incognito mode, to no avail. Any help?

Comment: If your rules are in htaccess then you must remove the leading slash from pattern. RewriteRule's pattern is relative to the directory htaccess is located in. ` `RewriteRule ^(.*) /#$1 [NE,R=302]` should work.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! Got me most of the way there. I ended up here to avoid an looping redirect and hiding my resource files:

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resources/*
    RewriteRule ^([^#]+) /#$1 [NE,R=302]

Comment: You need to use conditions before your Rule to avoid Redirecting your existing files and folders. 

Include these 2 lines before your RewriteRule 

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` .

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Much cleaner than my solution.