# Rewrite rule to direct to anchor on page (in context of other rewrite rules)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file in my domain root.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/services/(.+) /services#$1 [NE]
```

The first instructions force HTTPS and directs all requests to a PHP file (e.g. `/services` -> `/services.php`).

The last instruction is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686157/8289095), aiming to redirect path components after `/services` to an anchor on that page (e.g. `/services/item` -> `/services#item`). However, it does not work and yields a 404 error.

I thought it might be due to the other rules, but removing them did not help (and trying some variations did not help either, or made the server try to find `/services/item.php` for example.

How should I fix this? Do I need to put the rules in a different order? For clarity, I want to rewrite the URL, so that `.php` and `#` are not visible to the user.

Comment: `#` has to be visible to browser to be of any use as part after `#` is not even sent to your web server. Anchors are only processed in browser not handled by web server

Comment: @anubhava My understanding was that the # can be sent back from the server as part of the rewritten URL and then then browser navigate to the # anchor as normal. Is this not correct?  Would it be better to use a query string?

Comment: Yes that's correct `#` can be sent back from web server to browser but that goes against your requirement in the end `I want to rewrite the URL, so that .php and # are not visible to the user`

Comment: @anubhava Ah yes I see. The answer below uses a 301 redirect which keeps the # in the URL. I still have to test it.

Comment: Yes that's right approach but it needs some corrections and improvements.

Comment: @anubhava So would you recommend a query string approach instead?

Comment: Yes, definitely query string is better approach.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for your help and advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comments to answer to help out future visitors to easily find a quick solution.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# pass query parameter to a php file internally
RewriteRule ^services/([\w-]+)/?$ services.php?param=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# handle .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I’ll test this. Will it let me handle the final path component as a GET parameter in PHP?

Comment: yes, it will send part after `services/` as GET parameter to `service.php` with parameter name as `param`. You can modify it to whatever you want to call it.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your rules, check it:

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^services\/(.*)$ /services#$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This did indeed rewrite the URL as I hoped, but I did not realise that the URL part after # cannot be passed through, so I might need a different approach.